# Is there a way to filter bad words in Laravel using rule

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking to build a keyword filter rule i have successfully run `php artisan make:rule NoInvalidKeywords`

I have this in my NoInvalideKeywords.php

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
         return ! collect(explode(' ', $value))->contains(function ($word){
            return Str::contains($word, ['video']);
        });
    }
```

The code above doesn't check for case sensitivity for example if `Video` is given as title the rule is not checked.

Comment: So use [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert $word to lowercase then check:

```
function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
         return ! collect(explode(' ', $value))->contains(function ($word){
            return Str::contains(strtolower($word), ['video']);
        });
    }
```